# How can we make show/hide password input in angular js with bootstrap 3?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, passwords, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to make show/hide password input in angularjs with Bootstrap 3.

The toggle option needs to be inside the input.

Can you provide a snippet or example on that.

Thanks a million.

[image: Sample of it]

Answer (score 32):

You can dynamically change the input type with the ng-attr-type directive. For example:

```
<input ng-attr-type="{{ showPassword ? 'text' : 'password' }}">
```

you can tie the showPassword to the click event and make it toggle.

**Update (from @Ferie's comment)**:

HTML

```
<span class="showPassword" ng-click="togglePassword()">{{ typePassword ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }}</span><br> <input type="{{ typePassword ? 'text' : 'password' }}" name="password" placeholder="Password">
```

In the Angular Controller

```
$scope.togglePassword = function () { $scope.typePassword = !$scope.typePassword; };
```

Comment: to be 100% valid HTML, you'll need to add the `type="password"` as well, but at angular runtime this will be replaced.  Just a tip for anyone that has any kind of automatic HTML validation tooling.

Comment: **HTML**
`<span class="showPassword" ng-click="togglePassword()">{{ typePassword ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }}</span><br>
                <input type="{{ typePassword ? 'text' : 'password' }}" name="password" placeholder="Password">`
**In the Angular Controller**
`$scope.togglePassword = function () {
            $scope.typePassword = !$scope.typePassword;
        };`

Answer (score 8):

**AngularJS / UI Bootstrap Solution**

- Use Bootstrap's [has-feedback](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) class to show an icon inside the input field.
- Make sure the icon has `style="cursor: pointer; pointer-events: all;"`
- Use `ng-if` to show/hide different forms where the `<label type="password">` vs `<label type="text">`

*HTML*

```
<!-- index.html snippet -->    

<!-- show password as type="password" -->
<div ng-if="!showPassword"
       class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label>password</label>
    <input type="password"
           ng-model="params.password"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="type something here...">
    <span ng-if="params.password"
          ng-click="toggleShowPassword()"
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open form-control-feedback" 
          style="cursor: pointer; pointer-events: all;">
    </span>
  </div>

  <!-- show password as type="text" -->
  <div ng-if="showPassword"
       class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label>password</label>
    <input type="text"
           ng-model="params.password"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="type something here...">
    <span ng-if="params.password"
          ng-click="toggleShowPassword()"
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close form-control-feedback" 
          style="cursor: pointer; pointer-events: all;">
    </span>
  </div>
```

*JavaScript*

```
// app.js

var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.params = {};
    $scope.showPassword = false;
    $scope.toggleShowPassword = function() {
        $scope.showPassword = !$scope.showPassword;
    }
});
```

Give it as spin with the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oCEfTa?p=preview

Comment: Why do u use:  $scope.params = {}; ?

Comment: @grep `$scope.params` is just an object for holding variables. `$scope.params.password` gets set by angular's `ng-model="params.password"` in the html. You'd probably have a login or sign up button that triggers some function that would access the variables in $scope.params.

Answer (score 6):

you can simply do

```
<input ng-show="showpassword" type="text" ng-model="password">
<input ng-hide="showpassword" type="password" ng-model="password">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showpassword" ng-checked="false">
```

read [here](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-create-form-showhide-password-system-angularjs)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried this but I have like to have  what I have added in edited answer how can make it out from this.

Comment: To round out this excellent answer, here's the Bootstrap info requested: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups Use an input-group-addon.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a working demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showPassword = false;

  $scope.toggleShowPassword = function() {
    $scope.showPassword = !$scope.showPassword;
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="loginCtrl" novalidate>
  <label>
    Password:

    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" ng-attr-type="{{ showPassword ? 'text':'password'}}" />
    <div ng-click="toggleShowPassword()" ng-class="{'fa fa-eye': showPassword,'fa fa-eye-slash': !showPassword}" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>

  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this one

```
<input type="{{showPassword?'text':'password'}}" />
<input type="checkbox" title="Show Password" ng-model="showPassword" ng-checked="showPassword">
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a unique input and toggle his type like this:

```
<input type="{{inputType}}" placeholder="Put your password" />
```

Controller

```
  // Set the default value of inputType
  $scope.inputType = 'password';      
  // Hide & show password function
  $scope.hideShowPassword = function(){
    if ($scope.inputType == 'password')
      $scope.inputType = 'text';
    else
      $scope.inputType = 'password';
  };
```

http://codepen.io/gymbry/pen/fJchw/

Answer (score 0):

The simple and smart way is

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input tabindex="2" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="_password" placeholder="password" name="_password" required  ng-attr-type="{{ pwd_hide ? 'text':'password'}}">
  <span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="pwd_hide = !pwd_hide">{{ pwd_hide ? 'Hide':'Show'}}</span>
</div>
<span ng-show="submitted || loginForm._password.$dirty && loginForm._password.$invalid">
  <span ng-show="loginForm._password.$error.required" class="error">Please enter your password.</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="form-control" type="{{passwordType}}" ng-model="User.Password" name="txtPassword" ng-class="submitted?'ng-dirty':''" autofocus required /><i style="position: relative;float: right;top: -26px;right: 3px; cursor:pointer" ng-click="showPassword()" class="ti ti-eye"></i>
```

App.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.passwordType = "password";

```
$scope.showPassword = function () {

        if ($scope.passwordType == "password") {
            $scope.passwordType = "text";
        } else {
            $scope.passwordType = "password";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please describe your answer and do not only post source code!

Answer (score 0):

you should try to this one whit eye icons

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-init="paninptype='password'; iconimg='/images/icons8-invisible-32.png';">
                            <label>PAN Number</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="{{paninptype}}" class="form-control" name="PAN" ng-model="vm.step1.model.PAN" id="exp-pan" placeholder="e.g. FARPS XXXX G" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <img src="{{iconimg}}" class="pull-right" style="width:38px" ng-click="paninptype=(paninptype=='password'?'text':'password'); iconimg=(paninptype=='password'?'/images/icons8-invisible-32.png':'/images/icons8-eye-50.png');">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You want the input box to be hidden or show/hide password?

Here is what i have done till now

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <input ng-hide="hidevar" id="searchinput" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" >
      <span id="searchclear" ng-click="hideinpbox();">HIDE</span>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#searchinput {
    width: 200px;
}

#searchclear {
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:14px;
    margin-top:7px;
    margin-right:5px;
    font-size:14px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ccc;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/TfKvlh1mM6wsNrPQKY4Q?p=preview